# Gmail stops refreshing when I leave the tab open

Tags: gmail

Sometimes my Gmail tab will stop updating with new mails. These are just regular mails sent to my Gmail account, not being forwarded from another address. It seems to be that the page has lost its connection somehow, because a refresh seems to fix it fine.

The chat at the side also seems to disconnect, which to me suggests that the page is being disconnected somehow.

I leave Gmail on all the time in work so I can be notified of emails and refer back to them easily. Not seeing an email for multiple hours is pretty inconvenient then. How can I prevent this and make sure that it continues refreshing indefinitely?

If it matters, I'm using Chrome on Windows 7.

Comment: How long does it work before it stops?

Comment: I think it's in the scale of an hour or hours. I haven't gotten a clear idea, but I'll try pay attention and gauge it tomorrow.